# "CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE" error with QPython (Android)

Tags: android, subprocess, qpython, android-activitymanager

I'm trying to build a simple [Telegram bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots) to start and stop an old Samsung device working as a security cam.

All is good via ssh, so the commands involved have been already proved to be working. It's now a matter of moving them to *QPython* and the [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org/) lib.

Also the bot is already working, running from the device itself. The problem are the commands involving shell calls, as this one (QPython shell is running with *root* privileges):

```
am start -n com.pas.webcam/.Rolling
```

This should open the [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam) app.
In the QPython's script or console, if I do:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(['/system/bin/am', 'start', '-n', 'com.pas.webcam/.Rolling'])
```

...I have the error:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "app_process": \
cannot locate symbol "jpeg_crop_scanline" referenced by "/system/lib/libskia.so"...
```

...with exit code `-6`

From what I understand, there's a problem with a library when the IP webcam app is opened from the QPython shell. I cannot find any reference to similar issues.

Any idea on how can I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/data/data/com.pas.webcam/lib'
```

This is the app's lib path inside the userdata partition. It's not clear to me why the `am` binary can't find it if launched from QPython.

After that:

```
cmd = call(['/system/bin/am', 'start', '-n', 'com.pas.webcam/.Rolling'])
```

...finally works.